# Is there a way to customize search with "Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) library to perform an autocomplete search. What it does right now is: if I have 3 elements in the *lookup* tag - let's say "aa", "ba", "bb" - if I type the letter 'a' I get both "aa" and "ba" in the suggestion box. What I want is that if I type 'a' I only get "aa" as result in the suggestion box; if I type 'b' I get both "ba" and "bb" because they both start with letter 'b'.

Thank you in advance to anyone.

The code is pretty simple, since I had no idea how to perform the search I'm looking for.

CODE:

```
var countries = [
   { value: 'Andorra', data: 'AD' },
   // ...
   { value: 'Zimbabwe', data: 'ZZ' }
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: countries,
    lookupLimit: 10
});
```

Comment: What does your current filter function look like? You cant expect any help without showing your code.

Comment: I updated the question with the code.

Comment: Learn to read the documentation. `lookupFilter: function (suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {} filter function for local lookups. By default it does partial string match (case insensitive).` you can provide your own filter function and filter how you want to https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: That says nothing to me. What I need is an example. I was able to get to that point, I don't know how to filter.

Comment: How does that say nothing to you? You define the `lookupFilter` function on the object passed to `.autocomplete`. It should return a bool

Comment: How do I say to that lookupFilter to search only elements starting with what I type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation you'll find

> lookupFilter: function (suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {} filter
>   function for local lookups. By default it does partial string match
>   (case insensitive).

So, all you have to do is define the function how you want it to filter suggestions.

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: countries,
    lookupLimit: 10
    lookupFilter: function (suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {
      return suggestion.value.toLowerCase().startsWith(queryLowerCase)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I just didn't know the meaning of the variables "query" and "queryLowerCase".

Comment: So when you type in the search box, that library is going to call the `lookupFilter` function and pass it the search term as `query`, the search term lowercased as `queryLowerCase`, and then the suggestion is the current suggestion being iterated on. So it iterates through your country list (`lookup`) and uses the `lookupFilter` to determine if a country is a suggestion or not. This is how most if not all autosuggestions libraries work. You give it a data set, a max limit of suggestions to return, and a filter function.